# Mostrar imágenes desde una carpeta en Php

Tags: php, archivo

Estoy intentando mostrar en una pagina de mi sitio web una serie de imágenes que tengo en una carpeta. Esto es a lo que he llegado pero me salen una serie de errores. ¿Sabéis que puede ser?

> Warning:
>   opendir(../assest/images/baul/numerosletras/,../assest/images/baul/numerosletras/):
>   El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada. (code: 3) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php on line 20
>
> Warning: opendir(../assest/images/baul/numerosletras/): failed to open
>   dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php on
>   line 20
>
> Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php on line 21
>
> Warning: closedir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php on line 29

```
 <?php
$directory="assest/images/baul/numerosletras/";
$dirint = dir($directory);
while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
{
    if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
        echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
    }
}
$dirint->close();
```

?>

Edito lo que ya tenía con lo que me ha puesto el compañero. He descubierto que el problema era la primera barra..quitaándola llega bien a la ruta.
Ahora tengo otro error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function eregi() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php on line 22

Comment: "El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada" eso significa que la ruta que estás usando no existe. Verifica la ruta en su sistema de directorios y pon la correcta. Sin tener ninguna información me aventuro a decir que cambies "assest" por "assets" en la ruta, ya que "assets" si es una palabra del diccionario anglosajón y es posible que sea un error tipográfico.

Comment: Intenta insertar la ruta así `$ruta = "\assest\images\baul\numerosletras\";` por alguna razón cuando lo intentaba hacer de la otra forma, no encontraba el archivo, pero sí lo hago así, funciona, ojalá te sirva

Comment: La ruta está bien, si que me he equivocado al escribir la palabra pero así está la carpeta y tengo más cosas en esa ruta que funcionan  bien. Lo de las barras al revés no funciona.
El archivo .php está en la raiz y a lo que intento llamar en esa subcarpeta puede ser que esté lejos o habrá que indicar la ruta de otra forma en php?

Comment: Revisa que la función que estás llamando se llame así, el error dice que esta funcion: `eregi("gif", $archivo)` no existe

Comment: Vale, creo que está eleminada y ahora se usa preg_match aunque no tengo ni idea cómo

Answer (score 0):

1. Poner todas las imágenes en una carpeta, en este caso las pondremos en la carpeta img.
   Creamos un archivo `.php` en blanco llamado `galeria.php`, y lo guardamos en el mismo directorio de la carpeta `img`.

```php
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Imágenes dinámicas de una carpeta en php</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Dentro de la etiqueta `body` insertamos el código `php.`

```php
<body>
<?php

?>
</body>
```

Definimos una variable con la dirección de la carpeta de imágenes.

```php
<?php`introducir el código aquí`
    $directory="img";
?>
```

Definimos una variable `$dirint` y la igualamos a la función `dir()` de `PHP`, la cual leerá la carpeta de imágenes y nos retornará un `Array` de la clase `Directory` de `PHP.`

```php
<?php
    $directory="img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
?>
```

Creamos un ciclo `while` que procese el `Array` `$dirint`, la variable $archivo tendrá la información de cada archivo de la carpeta. Después imprimimos en el `html` cada variable, por el método echo para comprobar que la lectura es correcta, al final cerramos el directorio `$dirint->close()`.

```php
<?php
    $directory="img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        echo $archivo;
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería algo similar a:

```php
<body>
.
..
imagenes (01).jpg
imagenes (02).jpg
imagenes (03).jpg
imagenes (04).jpg
imagenes (05).jpg
imagenes (06).jpg
imagenes (07).jpg
imagenes (08).jpg
imagenes (09).jpg
imagenes (10).jpg
imagenes (11).jpg
imagenes (12).jpg
imagenes (13).jpg
imagenes (14).jpg
</body>
```

Creamos un condicional `if` para que solo sean procesados los archivos `png`, `gif` y `jpg`. Imprimimos también la variable `$directory` para obtener la `url` completa de cada imagen.

```php
<?php
    $directory="img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
            echo $directory."/".$archivo;
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería algo similar a:

```php
<body>
img/imagenes (01).jpg
img/imagenes (02).jpg
img/imagenes (03).jpg
img/imagenes (04).jpg
img/imagenes (05).jpg
img/imagenes (06).jpg
img/imagenes (07).jpg
img/imagenes (08).jpg
img/imagenes (09).jpg
img/imagenes (10).jpg
img/imagenes (11).jpg
img/imagenes (12).jpg
img/imagenes (13).jpg
img/imagenes (14).jpg
</body>
```

Por último imprimimos las imágenes en el formato `html`.

```php
<?php
    $directory="img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
            echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería algo similar a:

```php
<body>
<img src="img/imagenes (01).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (02).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (03).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (04).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (05).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (06).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (07).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (08).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (09).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (10).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (11).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (12).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (13).jpg"> 
<img src="img/imagenes (14).jpg">
</body>
```

El resultado final del archivo `galeria.php` debe ser:

```php
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Imágenes dinámicas de una carpeta en php</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $directory="img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
            echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero. Pero aún así quiero mantener la ruta que tengo para tenerlo organizado. Si tengo el .php en la raiz y las imágenes en la ruta /assest/images/baul/numerosletras/ si cambio el $directory por el que me interesa sigue sin encontrarlo. No entiendo

Comment: He probado tu función pero me da este error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function eregi() in C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\numerosletras.php on line 22

Comment: He estado investigando y la función eregi ya no vale. Se usa preg_match

Comment: Tienes que usar preg_match tal y como indica puluku

Answer (score 0):

mira a mi tampoco me reconoce esa funcion que coloco nuestro compañero pero resolvi lo de la galeria de esta forma, reutilizando para de su codigo.

```
<?php

 $directory="img/";
    $dirint = dir($directory);

    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) != false)
    {
        if (strpos($archivo,'jpg') || strpos($archivo,'jpeg')){
            $image = $directory. $archivo;
            echo'<img src='.$image. '>';
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();

?>
```

Prueba y me dices si te funciono, la funcion strpos es nativa de php para los strings y asi pude validar los formatos de la imagen